# How to decorate inherited method - Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have to decorate a inherited method, but it decorates all inherited methods. Basically I have to create a decorator that will decorate just one method from the class.

The test looks like this

```
@my_decorator
    class TestClass(Subclass):
        pass

t = TestClass()
t.say_hi
```

Let's say my SubClass looks like this

```
class SubClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hi():
        print("Hi")

    def say_wow():
        print("wow")
```

Now I have to make `my_decorator`, that has to decorate inherited function `say_hi()` to `print("*****")` before it prints "Hi"

I tried doing it like this, but than the decorator applies to all methods from `SubClass`

```
def my_decorator(cls)
    def say_hi():
        print("*********")
        cls.say_hi()

    return say_hi()
```

Naturally It applies to every function of the subclass, but how do I make it to apply to only a `say_hi()` function? -It also returns an `TypeError "NoneType" object is not callable`

Comment: There is a big difference between decorating a class and decorating a single method *in* that class. The decorator you show, errors aside, looks like it replaces `SubClass` with `None` after *calling* its `say_hi` method.

Comment: Thats what I dont know how to do. I want to decorate only one method of TestClass

Comment: You ... decorate the method, not the class.

Comment: Im sorry, quite new to python, still I cant decorate just the method because those are test data and i cant change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us fix `SubClass`, because instance methods require an explicit instance parameter at definition time:

```
class SubClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hi")

    def say_wow(self):
        print("wow")
```

Now you want the decorator to replace the `say_hi` method with a method that prints `'****'` before calling the original method. Le us write a decorator that just does that(*):

```
def my_decorator(cls):
    orig = cls.say_hi          # save the original method
    def say_hi(self):          # define a new one
        print('****')
        return orig(self)      # ... calling the original method
    cls.say_hi = say_hi        # replace the method in the class
    return cls
```

You can then use:

```
@my_decorator
class TestClass(SubClass):
    pass
t = TestClass()
t.say_hi()
```

and get as expected:

```
****
Hi
```

---

(*) this is a very simple decorator that can only replace a `say_hi(self)` method: neither a different name, nor additional parameters, but decorators can be much smarter...

Comment: Thank you sooo much, it works now perfectly. My first program that I write in python so it drove me nuts :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decorate a method, then decorate the method, not the class that contains it. If you want a *new* class, then the decorator applied to the class needs to return a class.

```
def print_banner(f):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
       print("****")
       f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _

class SubClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @print_banner
    def say_hi(self, ):
        print("Hi")

    def say_wow(self):
        print("wow")
```

Comment: However, I am not the one decorating the class, but I get tests that will run on my program and it requires that i make a decorator for this TestClass. It is an exercise, otherwise I would just decorate the inherited method